# "Fun" C++ library that interprets ASCII figures in code - what is it called? ("Multi-Dimensional Analog Literals")

Tags: c++, ascii-art

A while ago I stumbled upon a C++ gem, a set of classes that through operator overloading and possibly some preprocessor tricks, let you define variables using in-code ASCII art:

```
Line x = |-----|;    //x is 5
Line y = |---|;      //y is 3

Rectangle r = +---+
              |   |
              +---+; //r is 3 by 1
```

and IIRC, it even had support for 3D figures!

But for the life of me I cannot remember the name of this library/header file/set of classes. What is it called?

Comment: I remember seeing it somewhere a while ago, but never looked into it.  It looks hilarious!  Nothing I'd ever use in developement though! :p

Comment: Based on your title I thought you were talking about figlets http://www.figlet.org/

Comment: @Brian: It could have fooled me. Oh, wait.

Comment: This kind of fun hijacking of the C++ syntax also leads to the much more serious boost::spirit. http://boost-spirit.com/home

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you are after Multi-Dimensional Analog Literals

http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml

Comment: Mirrored and expanded (with a less constrained syntax and support for 0-unit widths/lengths/heights) here: https://github.com/Quuxplusone/analog-literals